# Splash Screen Video ReactNative Expo Router

Tags: react-native, expo, splash-screen, expo-router

guys! How do I put a spash screen video at the start of my application, and I'm using expo router, as there's no app.tsx input, how do I get it to run? I already have the Expo AV. My files are organized like this:

[Folders and files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKbPQ.png)

[_Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HlW4.png)

I managed to make the video run by creating a new screen for it and giving it a name of index.tsx, however it runs and doesn't go to the second screen which would be the welcome screen.

welcome screen acctually is "index.tsx"